# How can I open an URL in a hidden tab in Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I'm developing a Firefox add-on and want to get the document content (DOM Elements) of an URL for parsing some data but don't want user to see this action. Is there any way to open an URL in a hidden tab and get the document content of this tab? Or any other solution?

Comment: I don't really know about FF add-ons, but why not use Ajax, simply ?

Comment: I want to parse content of any URL and traverse the document content by DOMPath, and Ajax only return text result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use Javascript to do that. Have a closer look at the **xmlhttpRequest** function.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Ajax only return text result and I can't find any HTML parser to parse the response string and traverse it like a DOM tree

Comment: Hm? Maybe i did't get your Question - XHR  is a DOM API, you will get a Dom-document-object, you can simply add it to your current Dom. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: I mean the result of XHR is text, right? For example, if i call XHR function for http://www.google.com, will I get result in text format or DOM object format?

Comment: You can get the result as String or XML, both can be passed to a parser (eg. parser=new DOMParser(); xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");)